# How to combine three lists of objects by primary key using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, linq-to-objects

I'm trying to combine 3 lists of objects. I have a person list, address list and an addressRelation list.
I want to combine these lists into a new list ordered by person.id, use it as a datasource for a listview, and then be able to access the properties in the aspx page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Roughly

```
using System.Linq;

class Person
{
    public int Id; 
    public string Name;
}

class Address
{
    public int Id;
    public string Street;
}

class PersonAddress
{
    public int PersonId, AddressId;
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var personList = new []
        {
            new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Pete" },
            new Person { Id = 2, Name = "Mary" },
            new Person { Id = 3, Name = "Joe" }
        };

        var addressList = new []
        {
            new Address { Id = 100, Street = "Home Lane" },
            new Address { Id = 101, Street = "Church Way" },
            new Address { Id = 102, Street = "Sandy Blvd" }
        };

        var relations = new [] 
        {
            new PersonAddress { PersonId = 1, AddressId = 101 },
            new PersonAddress { PersonId = 3, AddressId = 101 },

            new PersonAddress { PersonId = 2, AddressId = 102 },
            new PersonAddress { PersonId = 2, AddressId = 100 }
        };

        var joined = 
                    from par in relations
                    join p in personList
                        on par.PersonId equals p.Id
                    join a in addressList
                        on par.AddressId equals a.Id
                    select new { Person = p, Address = a };

        foreach (var record in joined)
            System.Console.WriteLine("{0} lives on {1}", 
                                   record.Person.Name, 
                                   record.Address.Street);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Pete lives on Church Way
Mary lives on Sandy Blvd
Mary lives on Home Lane
Joe lives on Church Way
```

Comment: updated with alternative way of treating the data (scales better with many properties, and supports updating them a lot better, made the data classes non-valuetypes for that reason)

Comment: Thanks so much! Now I gotta figure how to wire this up to a DataSource , databind to a listview, and access the properties in the aspx page

Comment: you "could" always build your joins in SQL Server, and when you generate your DBML file it will generate the joins for you. Then you can access a person's address with `Person.Address.Street`. The above approach is a good decoupled approach that works best is EF Code First.

Comment: yeah, I'm not using a dbml file. Was doing this to learn Linq and really wanted to see how much of pain it would be doing it strictly with returned lists.

Comment: @Anton: fixed it myself; I was right in that it wasn't going to work but the fix was simply reordering the table scans. (See the demo live on http://ideone.com/qTVI5)