# WPF - How to binding from two linked collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

First class contains  idGendre

```
public class  Book: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    private int idGendre;
}
```

Second class contains a description of contains a description of

```
public class  Gendre: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int idGendre;
    private string gendre;
}
```

Class with collections

```
public class Data
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Book> _booksCollection;
        private ObservableCollection<Gendre> _gendresCollection;
    }
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding BooksCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
          <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Gendre id" Binding="{Binding IdGendre}"/>   
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Gendre name" Binding="{Binding IdGendre, Converter={StaticResource convertor}}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Gendre Name" Binding="{?????????????}"/>  
          </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

WPF Code behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Data data;      
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            data= new data();
            DataContext = data;
        }
    }
```

I try `IValueConverter` but i can use it just like that

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                switch (value.ToString().ToLower())
                {
                    case "1":
                        return "scify";
                    case "2":
                        return "comics";
                         }
                return "";
            }
```

Is there way to binding from another collection with key from primary?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new collection by joining Books and Gendre collection, select the required Properties and bind this collection to the DataGrid.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160031/how-to-combine-three-lists-of-objects-by-primary-key-using-linq) might help you.